# How to reverse the direction of array's elements?

Tags: javascript

Here's what i'm thinking about:

```
var a = ["fourth", "third", "second", "first", "zero"];
```

So now `a[0] === "fourth", a[1] === "third"...` and so on. I want to change the direction of the items, so they values will be equilalent to they place in the array like this: `a[0] === "zero", a[1] === "first"...`.

Comment: `a.reverse()` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function.

```js
var a = ["fourth", "third", "second", "first", "zero"];
a.reverse(); 
    
console.log(a)
```